# how to get the values from the XML

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

I wants use google weather api in my project. [here](http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=nabha) I am struggling from long time. to get the current temperature. city, humidity,day of week etc

I successfully hit the url. but I not know exact what i do in foundCharacter method to fetch the value.

Thanks

```
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementname       namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"weather"]) 
    {
            currentTweet = [Tweet alloc];
    }
}

 - (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"city"]) 
     {

     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the code:

```
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementname       namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"weather"]) 
    {
            currentTweet = [Tweet alloc];
    }
    else if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"city"]) 
    {
          currentTweet.city = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"city"]
    }
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
 {
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"weather"]) 
     {
           NSLog("Current City: %@",currentTweet.city);
     }
 }
```

For this type of xml, you don't want to use the `parser:foundCharacters:`

Quote from NSXMLPareser reference guide about `foundCharacters` method:

> Sent by a parser object to provide its delegate with a string
>   representing all or part of the characters of the current element.
>
> The parser object may send the delegate several
>   parser:foundCharacters: messages to report the characters of an
>   element. Because string may be only part of the total character
>   content for the current element, you should append it to the current
>   accumulation of characters until the element changes.

For more details: [NSXML Parser Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html),
[Working of parser](http://homepages.ius.edu/rwisman/C490/html/nsxmlparser.htm),[`foundCharacters` use](http://4arrowsmedia.com/blog/2010/06/17/iphone-xml-parsing/)